# 四則演算の単項演算子を変数に入れて数値に適応させる方法

Tags: ruby

二項演算子を用いるときは以下のように演算子を変数に入れて扱えますが

```
sign = :+
1.send(sign, 2) #=> 3
sign = :-
1.send(sign, 2) #=> -1
```

同じように単項演算子としての`+`,`-`を変数に入れて扱うことはできますか？
以下のような動作を期待しています。

```
sign = :+
1.apply(sign) #=> 1
sign = :-
1.apply(sign) #=> -1
```

Comment: ["@" Ruby 2.7.0 リファレンスマニュアル](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/2.7.0/doc/symref.html#at)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sign = :+@
1.send(sign) #=> 1
sign = :-@
1.send(sign) #=> -1
```